# How can I select the earliest date from a dataframe after a given cutoff date?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have three dataframes, one containing cutoff dates, one containing delivery dates, and a third with orders

```
import pandas as pd
cutoff = pd.DataFrame({'State': ['New Jersey','Idaho','Hawaii','Oklahoma'], 
         'January': ['2022-01-10','2022-01-17','2022-01-11','2022-01-15'],
         'February': ['2022-02-15','2022-02-17','2022-02-11','2022-02-15'],
         'March': ['2022-03-15','2022-04-17','2022-03-11','2022-03-15'],
         'April': ['2022-04-15','2022-04-17','2022-04-11','2022-04-15'],
         'May': ['2022-05-15','2022-05-17','2022-05-11','2022-05-15'],
         'June': ['2022-06-15','2022-06-17','2022-06-11','2022-06-15'],
         'July': ['2022-07-15','2022-07-17','2022-07-11','2022-07-15'],
         'August': ['2022-08-15','2022-08-17','2022-08-11','2022-08-15'],
         'September': ['2022-09-15','2022-09-17','2022-09-11','2022-09-15'],
         'October': ['2022-10-15','2022-10-17','2022-10-11','2022-10-15'],
         'November': ['2022-11-15','2022-11-17','2022-11-11','2022-11-11'],
         'December': ['2022-12-15','2022-12-17','2022-12-11','2022-12-15']})

deliverydates = pd.DataFrame({'State': ['New Jersey','Idaho','Hawaii','Oklahoma'], 
         'January': ['2022-01-31','2022-01-30','2022-01-29','2022-01-31'],
         'February': ['2022-02-28','2022-02-27','2022-02-28','2022-02-28'],
         'March': ['2022-03-31','2022-04-30','2022-03-29','2022-03-31'],
         'April': ['2022-04-30','2022-04-30','2022-04-29','2022-04-30'],
         'May': ['2022-05-31','2022-05-30','2022-05-29','2022-05-31'],
         'June': ['2022-06-30','2022-06-30','2022-06-29','2022-06-30'],
         'July': ['2022-07-31','2022-07-30','2022-07-29','2022-07-31'],
         'August': ['2022-08-31','2022-08-30','2022-08-29','2022-08-31'],
         'September': ['2022-09-30','2022-09-30','2022-09-29','2022-09-30'],
         'October': ['2022-10-31','2022-10-30','2022-10-29','2022-10-31'],
         'November': ['2022-11-30','2022-11-30','2022-11-29','2022-11-11'],
         'December': ['2022-12-31','2022-12-30','2022-12-11','2022-12-31']})

orders =  pd.DataFrame({'Person': ['Lee','Smith','Johnson','Garcia'], 
         'State': ['New Jersey','Idaho','Hawaii','Oklahoma']})
```

I need to create a test that compares today's date with the cutoff date and assigns each order the next possible delivery date. For example, today is January 12. Smith is in Idaho. January 12 is before Idaho's January cutoff date (January 15th), so his delivery date is 1/30/2022.

Lee, however, is in New Jersey. Today (1/12) is after the January cutoff date (1/10), so his delivery date is now the next earliest delivery date (2/28).

The goal is to merge the correct delivery dates onto the orders dataframe for a result like so:

| Person | State | Delivery Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lee | New Jersey | 2022-02-28 |
| Smith | Idaho | 2022-01-30 |
| Johnson | Hawaii | 2022-02-28 |
| Garcia | Oklahoma | 2022-01-31 |

And if today were February 12, it would need to select the next possible delivery date, and so on.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proposed solution below. It uses grouping by 'State' to get the next item in a group, using `grouped.first()` after filtering the series to only allow dates which satisfy the test condition (being after today)

```
import datetime
today = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


def fill_orders(test_date, orders_df, cutoff_df, deliverydates_df):
 # Get a flat file of cutoff dates
 cutoffs_series = cutoff_df.set_index('State').stack()

 # Get next date after test_date
 next_cutoff = cutoffs_series[cutoffs_series > test_date].groupby(by='State').first()
 next_cutoff.name='nextcutoff'

 # Get flat delivery dates
 flat_delivery_dates = deliverydates_df.set_index('State').stack().to_frame('deliverydate')

 # Join next cutoff date
 joined = flat_delivery_dates.join(next_cutoff)

 # Get next delivery date after next cutoff
 next_delivery = joined.loc[joined['nextcutoff'] <= joined['deliverydate'], :].groupby(by=['State']).first()['deliverydate']

 # Join to orders
 return orders_df.merge(next_delivery, left_on='State', right_index=True)

fill_orders(today, orders, cutoff, deliverydates)
```

Comment: I think this is getting close - yet if I run it today it is giving me the delivery dates a month later than what I need. I think something is going awry at the next_delivery stage

Comment: I just ran it and all delivery dates in February, which should be correct because January 19th (today) is after all of the cutoff dates in January? Unless you are expecting different behaviour?